# Java string split regex non-capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy, capturing-group

I am trying to split the string on "." Except when a part of the string is in [ ] then I just want to return what is inside the brackets.

I have the following line of code:

```
"blah.blah[http://blah.blah.com/blah/blah#]".split(("(\\.|\\[(?=.*\\]))")
```

This returns:

```
 [ "blah", "blah", "http:blah", "blah", "com/blah/blah#]" ]
```

If instead I try:

```
"blah.blah[http://blah.blah.com/blah/blah#]".split(("(\\.|\\[(?:.*\\]))")
```

I get:

```
["blah", "blah"]
```

I'm not sure how I need to define my non capturing group so that it will split on the first [ but not capture anything after up to and including the ]

Just to clarify the array I am expecting back is

```
["blah", "blah", "http://blah.blah.com/blah/blah#"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, the best option is to use the "find" method instead of split with this pattern:

```
(?<=\\[)[^\\]]*(?=\\])|[^\\][.]+
```

Note that the order of the alternatives is important because the first win. So `(?<=\\[)[^\\]]*(?=\\])` must be before `[^\\][.]+`

[demo](http://fiddle.re/0max66)

Comment: The find here would match the "." and return them. The goal is to get the strings between them.

Comment: @tiger13cubed: refresh your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help Casmir :) Not the solution I had in mind, but it does the trick. Any way you can explain what I was doing wrong with my \\[(?=.*\\])  regex?

Comment: @tiger13cubed: It's simple, a lookahead doesn't consume characters, it's only a check. So all the dots between square brackets can be matched. A pattern you can use with the split method is `\\.(?![^[]*])|[\\]\\[]` but it is far from an efficient way.

Comment: Where can I find the "find" method?

Comment: @fxm27: in `java.util.regex.*`

Comment: @Casimir Whoops. I was actually looking for this is Javascript and wasn't paying attention. Thank you!